# Reading multiple elements from a channel in Go

Tags: go, batch-processing, channel

I'm reading values from a channel in a loop like this:

```
for {
    capturedFrame := <-capturedFrameChan
    remoteCopy(capturedFrame)
}
```

To make it more efficient, I would like to read these values in a batch, with something like this (pseudo-code):

```
for {
    capturedFrames := <-capturedFrameChan
    multipleRemoteCopy(capturedFrames)
}
```

But I'm not sure how to do that. If I call `capturedFrames := <-capturedFrameChan` multiple times it's going to block.

Basically, what I would like is to read all the available values in `captureFrameChan` and, if none is available, it blocks as usual.

What would be the way to accomplish this in Go?

Comment: There is no way to batch read values from a channel. If you don't want to call `multipleRemoteCopy` multiple times just buffer the values locally.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've ended up doing it as below. Basically I've used `len(capturedFrames)` to know how many frames are available, then retrieved them in a loop:

```
for {
    var paths []string
    itemCount := len(capturedFrames)
    if itemCount <= 0 {
        time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)
        continue
    }

    for i := 0; i < itemCount; i++ {
        f := <-capturedFrames
        paths = append(paths, f)
    }

    err := multipleRemoteCopy(paths, opts)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error: could not remote copy \"%s\": %s", paths, err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Something like this should work:

```
for {
    // we initialize our slice. You may want to add a larger cap to avoid multiple memory allocations on `append`
    capturedFrames := make([]Frame, 1)
    // We block waiting for a first frame
    capturedFrames[0] = <-capturedFrameChan

forLoop:
    for {
        select {
        case buf := <-capturedFrameChan:
            // if there is more frame immediately available, we add them to our slice
            capturedFrames = append(capturedFrames, buf)
        default:
            // else we move on without blocking
            break forLoop
        }
    }

    multipleRemoteCopy(capturedFrames)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this (for channel `ch` with type `T`):

```
for firstItem := range ch {                      // For ensure that any batch could not be empty
    var itemsBatch []T
    itemsBatch = append(itemsBatch, firstItem)
Remaining: 
    for len(itemsBatch) < BATCHSIZE {            // For control maximum size of batch
        select {
        case item := <-ch:
            itemsBatch = append(itemsBatch, item)
        default:
            break Remaining
        }
    }
    // Consume itemsBatch here...
}
```

But, if `BATCHSIZE` is constant, this code would be more efficient:

```
var i int
itemsBatch := [BATCHSIZE]T{}
for firstItem := range ch {                      // For ensure that any batch could not be empty
    itemsBatch[0] = firstItem
Remaining:
    for i = 1; i < BATCHSIZE; i++ {              // For control maximum size of batch
        select {
        case itemsBatch[i] = <-ch:
        default:
            break Remaining
        }
    }
    // Now you have itemsBatch with length i <= BATCHSIZE;
    // Consume that here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `len(capturedFrames)`, you can do it like below:

```
for {
    select {
    case frame := <-capturedFrames:
        frames := []Frame{frame}
        for i := 0; i < len(capturedFrames); i++ {
           frames = append(frames, <-capturedFrames)
        }
        multipleRemoteCopy(frames)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems you can also benchmark just

```
for {
    capturedFrame := <-capturedFrameChan
    go remoteCopy(capturedFrame)
}
```

without any codebase refactoring to see if it increase efficiency.